# How to join two table with where between condition

Tags: mysql

I have two table name income and expenses. I want to join two table and get the data between the two date ranges value.

```
Income                  
=============         
id income_name      income_price income_date              
1  admission              30    2017-10-10
2  hostel                 40    2017-10-9
3  bus                    50    2017-10-7

expenses                  
=============
id expenses_name      expenses_price expenses_date              
1  furniture                30    2017-10-9
2  teacher                  40    2017-10-8
3  bus                      60    2017-10-7
```

I want to retrieve the data from two table between the date 2017-10-6 to 2017-10-10.please  help me.
Result Table
 =============

```
id income_name      income_price      expense_name       expenses_price             
    1  admission         30               furniture       30
    2  hostel           40                 teacher        40
    3  bus                50               bus            60
```

Comment: You possibly need a union rather than a join but it's not clear from your question. Maybe you could add your expected result?

Comment: Homework problems need to show effort to get help.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: This can help you: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp do you mean union two tables?

Comment: I have added the result table . Please find this and give me the best solution. Union does not work for me.

Comment: What is the homework problem by the way mr.Tim Biegeleisen.I don't know any idea about this type of problem. Can u explain more about it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I guess, you already have the answer in your question's title. [Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) the table (income and expenses) then add [where](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) condition. Or please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: SELECT i.income_title, i.income_price , e.expenses_title, expenses_.price From income i LEFT JOIN expenses e on i.income_date = e.expense_date WHERE i.income_date BETWEEN '2017-10-6' AND '2017-10-10'

Comment: Why join 2 tables using _date_ column instead of _id_ like `left join expenses e on i.id = e.id` ? Btw, you have a _typo_ in `expenses_.price `.

Comment: Could you write the actual query for this problem sir RubaMalam

Answer (score 2):

You can use the union operator to merge the result set of two or more queries

```
Select * from income where (date between 'your_start_date' and 'your_end_date')
UNION
Select * from expenses where (date between 'your_start_date' and 'your_end_date')
```

The `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use `UNION ALL`

Comment: SELECT i.income_title, i.income_price , e.expenses_title, expenses_.price From income i LEFT JOIN expenses e on i.income_date = e.expense_date WHERE i.income_date BETWEEN '2017-10-6' AND '2017-10-10'

Comment: Union does not give the desired output . I have already tested union. If u think u surely get the right answer from union then give me the whole sql queries on the behalf my question and its result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` to join result sets of the 2 tables from where you are getting the data. Below is the query.

```
select *
from Income
where date between '2017-10-6' and '2017-10-10'
union all
select *
from expenses
where date between '2017-10-6' and '2017-10-10';
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. Always add a short description.

Comment: Not working. I have added the result table . please find this and give me solution

Comment: Please share your desired output.

Comment: I have share the result table above . Actually i want to join the two table on the date range between the two dates.

Comment: How can you relate admission to furniture, hostel to teacher, bus to bus. You won't be able to join on dates as the dates of all the entities are different i.e. you can't join admission to furniture because date of admission is '2017-10-10' and date of furniture is '2017-10-9'.